# Zend Framework 2: Registering multiple custom view helpers externally

Tags: php, zend-framework2

ZF2 has a nice way to [register it's own Form View Helpers](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Form/View/HelperConfig.php).

Let's say I've got my own external library and have a folder with several custom view helpers. In which way could I use such a "HelperConfig"-file as Zend Form does (see above)? How would I register it in my Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class that implements `Zend\ServiceManager\ConfigInterface` (just like the example you provided) all you need is to pass in a ServiceManager instance.

This could easily be done in the `onBootstrap` in a Module class.

```
namespace MyModule;

use Some\Other\Namespace\MyCustomViewHelperConfig;
use Zend\EventManager\EventInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\BootstrapListenerInterface;

class Module implements BootstrapListenerInterface
{
    public function onBootstrap(EventInterface $event)
    {
        $application = $event->getApplication();
        $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
        $viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');

        $viewHelperConfig = new MyCustomViewHelperConfig();
        $viewHelperConfig->configureServiceManager($viewHelperManager);
    }
}
```